# Does converting an mp3 format audio file to m4a format makes audio quality better?

Tags: mp3, compression, sound-quality, compatibility, aac-m4a

Does converting an mp3 format audio file to m4a format makes audio quality better ?
I was just wondering if mp3 is lossy. How it can generate lossless m4a file after conversion.
I know mp3 can be converted to m4a but will this m4a file will give the same audio quality as compared to an originally created m4a file.

Comment: please look into lossless and lossy compression on wikipedia. that will explain more than a straight answer.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_data_compression

Comment: You can't "convert to m4a" -- m4a is a _container_ format, and may contain `AAC` (lossy) or `ALAC` (lossless) formats -- or even `mp3`.

Comment: @michael this might help explain to better to people who don't understand what a container is.  I think that is part of the problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WIIKXOrt3bk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Once lossy formats are encoded, any data not saved within the file is lost. You could convert a lossy MP3 to a WAV or an M4A file but the quality of the WAV or M4A would be exactly the same as the original MP3.

Comment: pfarley, are you sure there will not be any loss when transcoding from mp3 to m4a? this would only be the case if transcoding to a lossless format (despite the container (m4a/flac).

Comment: I wanted to stress that you won't get lost data back and was probably a bit misleading, sorry. If you converted to another lossy codec (even if it's 'higher-quality' than what you're converting from) you can still lose data.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you loose even more quality due to another file compression algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

It is mathematically impossible to improve any digital audio stream to a "Better Quality" by a simple conversion to said file type. A poor quality mp3 can be "converted" to any format you like but the poor quality will remain and, as mentioned, you may even lose a bit in the conversion.

There seems to be some misconceptions floating around out there about stepping up quality as many programs allow you to import lossy or low quality audio into a workspace that may be set at a high quality/resolution. That being said the lossy or low quality audio does not get any "better" in doing so. The fundamental problem is that you cant insert samples into a track. you can estimate them (although aliasing can be an issue) but you can't fundamentally insert them.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add & clarify that `m4a` is a *container* format, actually the [same spec as `mp4`, merely a different file extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14#.MP4_versus_.M4A), and therefore can *contain* either `AAC` (lossy) *or* `ALAC` (lossless) formats -- or even `mp3`! -- so the question as stated doesn't make sense (same with many of the answers & comments).

Regardless, the simple answer to the intended question is that converting a lossy format to a non-lossy format *inherently* can't make audio quality "better" (literally: no new information can be added to the data via this transformation). In theory, the *very best* you can do is achieve the same quality; in practice, you'll probably lose a little quality, but carefully [selecting the right conversion & format options](https://superuser.com/questions/593869/does-it-make-sense-converting-a-file-to-a-higher-audio-bitrate/593907#593907) you might not notice the degradation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, m4a is also considered to be a lossy format. So converting from lossy to lossy would not make any difference, probably worsen the quality depending on the coding standard being used.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to understand: Rakesh, what is your motivation for converting? Also, within M4A, are you specifically referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless ?

Clarifying this will help with useful answers.

Comment: No, i am referring to m4a in general. And, i could not understand what you meant by 'motivation for converting' because in my view it does not matter because it won't change the result anyway.

Comment: I was just asking that 'how can one mp3 file (lossy) can generate an m4a file which is lossless.  But, i think @pfarley has clearified that even when we convert an mp3 fule to an m4a format, it will change the format but the quality will be the same as the source mp3 file.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to undo the losses done to an audio file. Once the audio is lost, it can never be re-obtained. If you want your audio to be lossless, you sadly have to re-record the whole thing and have the recording be initially saved as either wav if you want it to be uncompressed, flac if you want to compress it and are not an apple user, or alac if you want to compress it and you are an apple/mac user. So right back to the studio you go!